# Generate representative boolean queries from source text?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

Within conventional information retrieval systems, we use a boolean query to generate a result set that matches that query.

What does one call the 'task', where, given a known set of similar documents, determine the boolean query that best represents it?

The main issue I encounter right now is I don't know what this problem is called, so I am finding it difficult to discover existing literature and research on the topic.